# What is exploratory testing?

Tags: computer-science, exploratory

And how can i use it as part of my development cycle?

Im trying to answere this question for my computer science and i don't understand what he means by "part of my development cycle".

Answer (score 0):

exploratory testing is activity where tester tests the application (SUT - system under test) while exploring/knowing the features simultaneously. This style of testing the application is suited for tester who is not familiar with SUT. For more experienced tester or tester who is familiar with SUT, targetted or scripted testing is productive use of his time. More details @ [Exploratory testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_testing)

Comment: how can i use it as part of my development cycle?

Comment: In development cycle, you can use exploratory testing once sufficient features are added into SUT to allow exploration (there is no point in testing if you cannot test critical workflows/features of  SUT.)